# How to get Stripe Payout Id from Stripe Charge Id

Tags: c#, .net, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe API to handle payment in the project.

I have `Charge Id` and `Transfer Id` of a transaction and now I need to get `Payout Id`.

I have looked through the Stripe API documentation but wasn't able to figure out how to get it.

Can anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re using an automatic payout, you can see the charges included in the payout by retrieving the [List All Balance Transactions](https://stripe.com/docs/api/balance_transactions/list?lang=dotnet) and [expanding](https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects?lang=dotnet) the [source](https://stripe.com/docs/api/balance_transactions/object#balance_transaction_object-source) of the property. This will give you the transfer/ charge ids you’re looking for on the payout. However, there is no way to obtain the payout id directly from the transfer/ charges ids via the API.